# Conditional merge tags to compare dates not working

Tags: mailchimp

Conditional merge tags to compare dates not working.
I have a similar problem to: [Solved - Mailchimp Conditional Merge tags using a date field not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35501986/solved-mailchimp-conditional-merge-tags-using-a-date-field-not-working)

I am trying to compare current date with a date field in a list with merge tag DATE_FF.I tried multiple date formats for date, also the one in above older post: DATE:Y-m-d. Does not work. I am trying to output different content, depending if an email goes out before or after the date in DATE_FF.Logic below does not react to date comparison... neither greater nor smaller boolean seems to work. I always get NULL no matter what the date in the field.

Here the code:

DATE_FF:  *|DATE_FF|*
Test: DATE:d/m/Y : *|DATE:d/m/Y|*
*|IF:DATE_FF > DATE:d/m/Y|*
PRE Appt content
*|ELSEIF:DATE_FF < DATE:d/m/Y|*
POST Appt content
*|ELSE:|*
NULL
*|END:IF|*

and an example result:

DATE_FF:  31/05/2016
Test: DATE:d/m/Y : 15/05/2016
NULL

Answer (score 1):

ok... I had a lengthy chat with mailchimp support. here the answer. one cannot use dynamic merge tags and compare it in a condition. Above |DATE:d/m/Y| can be used to output current date but not in a condition. This statement would yield EMPTY at runtime. Hence you can only compare a date list field to a static date